# About the ::http::geturl token usage

Tags: http, tcl

I am learning TCL for my work and I have a question that I can not find the answer.

It concerns the usage of `::http::geturl` token.

Let's consider the following code:

```
package require http

set url "some url"
set token [::http::geturl $url]

# the question is about the line below
upvar #0 $token state

set data $state(body)
```

If I'm not doing a mistake, the use of `upvar` here is just creating an alias `state` referring to `token`.

I am wondering why is this line always written in any code I can see (even in the TCL documentation)?

To be more clear, is `set data $state(body)` equivalent to `set data $token(body)`?
And if it is the case, why do we write this `upvar` if it is not necessary (and not really useful but making the script heavier)?

On my laptop, I cannot install anything such as *tclsh* for now, so I could not perform the test to find the answer by myself.
This is why I require your help.

Thanks to anyone who will answer me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`token` actually contains a string, something like `::http::1` (the number increments the more calls you make to `::http::geturl`), and that string is the name of an array.

So when you do `$token(body)`, you are telling the code to find the value for the key `body` in the array `token`, except that this array doesn't exist. The array's actual name is `::http::1` as mentioned earlier. So it's easier to create an alias than to use something like, say, `lindex [array get $token body] 1`.

Comment: The http package provides commands for the most common things you might want to extract from the response. So to get the body you would normally use `http::data $token` instead of messing with upvar.